# Using Loader em API version prior to 11

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader, android-loadermanager

I am using a `CursorAdapter` and `ContentProvider`, and I want to use `CursorLoader`, so I reconfigured my project to target API 11 and set min-sdk-ver to 7. However it crashes when an `Activity` calls a sub-`Activity` which uses the `CursorLoader`. The error is `NoClassDefFoundError` delivered via `IllegalStateException`.

My question is can we use Honeycomb APIs in previous Android versions even if we have the same configs a have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wish to use `CursorLoader` in an Android application supporting pre-API Level 11 devices, you will need to use the Android Compatibility Library (ACL). You can download that via the SDK and AVD Manager and copy the JAR from your SDK installation into your project. Then, you will need to use `support.v4` versions of the loader classes, plus inherit from `FragmentActivity`, so you can call `getSupportLoaderManager()` to get your ACL edition of the `LoaderManager`.

[This blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html) describes (briefly) the ACL. A sample app using `CursorLoader` is found packaged with the ACL itself. You can also review [a tutorial on using ACL's edition of `CursorLoader`](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_loading-data_cursorloader/).

Comment: Thank you a lot, you don't even know how you've helped me. Thanks!